Laravel get token with SQL Server
I'm trying to make an authentication login with laravel Sanctum and get create the token using SQL Server and I have the following error:

SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Converting an nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: insert into [personal_access_tokens] ([name], [token], [abilities], [expires_at], [tokenable_id], [tokenable_type], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (insomnia, e1984b68e31dfba8268194d6f7190c65e2702904c4759084634086f970cc9830, ["*"], ?, 1, App\Models\User, 2024-09-24 12:12:03.047, 2024-09-24 12:12:03.047))

If I insert using a query, it works normally, passing the values ​​like this

insert into [personal_access_tokens] ([name], [token], [abilities], [expires_at], [tokenable_id], [tokenable_type], [updated_at], [created_at])
values ('insominia', 'd6f25421129a1ad0d05a82d83ded92859d4209272981f46c3b5377503dbfd312', '["*"]', CONVERT(datetime, '2050-02-23 06:20:24.000', 121), 1, 'App\Models\User', CONVERT(datetime, '2016-02-23 06:20:24.000', 121), CONVERT(datetime, '2016-02-23 06:20:24.000', 121))

Or using DB::raw:

DB::raw(insert into [personal_access_tokens] ([name], [token], [abilities], [expires_at], [tokenable_id], [tokenable_type], [updated_at], [created_at])
values ('insominia', 'd6f25421129a1ad0d05a82d83ded92859d4209272981f46c3b5377503dbfd312', '["*"]', CONVERT(datetime, '2050-02-23 06:20:24.000', 121), 1, 'App\Models\User', CONVERT(datetime, '2016-02-23 06:20:24.000', 121), CONVERT(datetime, '2016-02-23 06:20:24.000', 121)))

I tested the createToken function in the HasApiToken.php file in the vendor/sanctum folder.
My Laravel login function:
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    $token = $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
    return response()->json([
        'token' => $token,
        'user' => $user
    ]);
}


set language 'spanish'; select cast('2050-02-23 06:20:24.000' as datetime) fails for me. You need to use non-ambigious date string

This question is similar to: SQL Server not accepting YYYY-MM-DD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I can do inserts using a query in SQL Server, my problem is creating an authentication token through Laravel 10. If I try to use Insomnia, for example, to try to log in, I get the error above.

I think the ?, in the query is throwing things off. Can you show the code you're using?

Sounds like it doesn't properly support spanish date format, i'd say it's a bug.

@siggemannen eu não passo nenhum dado ao gerar o token para fazer a autenticação. O processo todo é feito numa função do Sanctum. Eu abri a função e adicionei uma consulta de insert para testar e funcionar, mas usando $token = $this->tokens()->create([ 'name' => $name, 'token' => hash('sha256' , $plainTextToken), 'habilidades' => $habilidades, 'expires_at' => $expiresAt, ]); dá o erro acima

I don't think it has anything to do with the Spanish language format, the Sanctum query is passing in a standard format. However, the expires_at value is passing in a ? instead of an actual value. I don't know if it's because createToken passes in a null value if the expires value isn't set or if it's something else. You may need to submit a bug report, though.

A non-ambiguous formatted datetime string includes a T between the date and time portions, i.e.: Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v. This guards against weird DATEFORMAT settings on SQL Server that can switch the interpretation of day and month portions in its absence. See, for example, db<>fiddle
